# Python - Tkinter frame's Configure event constantly firing, callback constantly being called

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am fairly new to Tkinter and am trying to build an application that contains table data within a scrollable canvas. I have designed a Table class that contains a Canvas widget, which in turn contains a Frame that contains the table content.

However, when trying to make the Canvas scroll-able, I am running into an issue. I have bound the table content's Configure event to a callback that sets the scroll region. However, when I run my application this callback is called forever in an infinite loop, and I am not sure why. I cannot figure out why the Configure event would be constantly firing.

Moreover, when trying to switch between tabs, my app will freeze, presumably because of the app being stuck in a loop of callback calls.

Below is a simplified example of what I am trying to do in my app. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this problem, while also allowing the table content to be scroll-able?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Table(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.table_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='cyan')
        table_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self.table_canvas,
            orient='vertical',
            command=self.table_canvas.yview)

        self.table_content = ttk.Frame(self.table_canvas)
        self.table_content.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

        self.table_canvas.create_window(
            (0, 0),
            window=self.table_content,
            anchor='nw')

        self.table_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=table_scrollbar.set)

        for _ in range(10):
            table_row = ttk.Frame(self.table_content)
            ttk.Label(
                table_row,
                text='left text'
            ).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
            ttk.Label(
                table_row,
                text='right text'
            ).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='e')
            table_row.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='same')
            table_row.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='same')
            table_row.pack(fill='x')

        self.table_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        table_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    def on_configure(self, event):
        print('on configure triggered')
        self.table_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.table_canvas.bbox('all'))


app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('600x600')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(app)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

container1 = ttk.Frame(tab1)

label_container1 = ttk.Frame(container1)
ttk.Label(label_container1, text='Tab One').pack(side='left')
label_container1.pack(fill='x')

table1 = Table(container1)
table1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

container1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

container2 = ttk.Frame(tab2)

label_container2 = ttk.Frame(container2)
ttk.Label(label_container2, text='Tab Two').pack(side='left')
label_container2.pack(fill='x')

table2 = Table(container2)
table2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

container2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(tab1, text='One')
notebook.add(tab2, text='Two')

notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of why this is happening, but the root cause seems to be that you're putting the scrollbar inside the canvas. As a rule of thumb, a scrollbar shouldn't be a child of the thing that it is scrolling.

If you move the scrollbar to be a child of the frame (`self`) instead of the canvas, the problem goes away.

```
table_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
    self,
    orient='vertical',
    command=self.table_canvas.yview)
```

Comment: could it be because since the parent is what it is scrolling and the scrollbar itself is changing when it is being scrolled (moves up and down) it cause the parent to change also and trigger `Configure` event?